# platform requirement not met error in wpf application

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I am getting following error while browsing wpf application  from windows 8.Its working in other machines .Do we need to do any configuration changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://nerddawg.blogspot.ru/2006/08/wpf-deployment-errors-and-what-they.html), the problem may happen because the target framework used on the dev machine is not installed on your client machine. Try installing .Net2.0 by clicking "Install .Net Framework" button.